# S3 copy data with original last_modified data

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966104/does-s3-copy-keep-versioning) question.

Since copying data in s3 from one region to another doesn't keep versioning info.  It was suggested to copy all the version to the new region for the key.  Thus keeping all the version info for that key. The problem now is when I copy versions over the `last_modified` date changes to the date and time it was copied over.  If a 100 versions get copied over then those 100 versions are in the span of a few seconds where originally they were in the span of a month. Is there a way to update the `last_modified` time to keep the original date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 does not allow you to specify or modify the `Last-Modified` value. The documentation indicates this implicitly, simply omitting `Last-Modified` from the list of supported request headers for the [PUT Object request](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html). There's also [a thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=209241) on the AWS forum on this topic.

If you need to save `Last-Modified` (e.g. as some of the S3 file syncing utilities do), you must ignore the value set by S3 and use your own custom header like `x-amz-meta-last-modified`.